Welcome message on the tour page
Right now we got this message on the tour page:

Cryptography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software developers, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about cryptography.

I think the term software developers is misleading, because those tend to care more about:

Libraries and their usage
Implementation of their own crypto code, possibly their own design

Usually questions in this direction are marked off-topic, e.g. because they are about implementation, programming or usage of cryptographic libraries. 
Although cryptographic protocols can be in the purview of software developers, most of our on-topic list in the help center are primarily adressed towards researchers / scientists in the field, who are only noted as "others" in the welcome message. 
I would suggest changing the message on the tour page in a manner to reflect the scientific focus of this site

I added a few answers so people can  vote, though if anyone has a better wording, feel free to add to the list.

How about this (emphasis added to highlight the change, would be removed before posting)

Cryptography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for cryptographers, mathematicians, computer scientists and others interested in cryptography. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about cryptography.


I went ahead and made this one the text on the tour. If the others ever get more votes, we can switch.

I liked this one, but why putting "mathematicians" before "cryptographers"?

@Vitor, I changed the order. Thanks.

No, we shouldn't change it at all. It is just fine the way it is.

How about this (emphasis added to highlight the change, would be removed before posting)

Cryptography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for cryptography enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about cryptography.


How about this (emphasis added to highlight the change, would be removed before posting)

Cryptography Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for mathematicians, information security professionals and others interested in cryptography. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about cryptography.

